# Radio Button Validation: I could validate it but I cant figure out the reason

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I was stuck trying to validate if a radiobutton was selected or not and, in consequence, show alerts. Well, I found the mistake (I was putting the conditional statement inside the loop).

Even I solved the problem, I can’t figure out yet why my code works correctly outside the loop but doesn’t work inside it. Now I'm stuck with this.

I appreciate if anyone can tell me what’s the reason.

Below you'll see both JS codes, but here you have the fiddles examples:

[JSFiddle that doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/LMqWD/)

[JSFiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/FKsJ7/)

This is the JS code that doesn’t work:

```
var getForm = document.getElementById('formX');
var putForm = getForm.onsubmit = showIt;

function showIt(){

  var getNames = document.getElementsByName('season');

  var result = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++){
    if(getNames[i].checked){
      result = true;
      break;
    } 
    if(result === false){
      alert('Please, choose an option');
      return false;
      }else{
        alert('You\'ve choosen ' + getNames[i].value)  
      } 
  }//Loop ends here.

}
```

And this is the JS code that works without problems:

```
var getForm = document.getElementById('formX');
var putForm = getForm.onsubmit = showIt;

function showIt(){

  var getNames = document.getElementsByName('season');

  var result = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++){
    if(getNames[i].checked){
      result = true;
      break;
    } 

  }//Loop ends here.
  if(result === false){
      alert('Please, choose an option');
      return false;
  }else{
    alert('You\'ve choosen ' + getNames[i].value)  
  }
}
```

Comment: See answer below, hope that helps.

Comment: You asked why it works when you do what you do. It's answered with the break statement, there's other people that agree for a reason. If not, feel free to look up what `break` does within a loop in `javascript`. Important point is that we stick with your actual question.

Comment: @BRogers Thanks for help me. Well I've realised if I use `break` inside a loop is as "convert" the loop in an if statement (something like that). That plus the conditional statement for the alerts is wrong.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to see that you're seeking to understand why it's working instead of just moving on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your `break;` line.

When it's inside the loop you're breaking it out on true before it has a chance to hit the following code: `if(result === false)`

`break` is breaking out of the entire loop which means it never hit's your `if(result===false)`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the for loop in JS code that doesn’t work has a wrong logic, it means that if the first radiobutton checked, the for loop stops; if the first radiobutton does not checked, it will alert 'Please, choose an option' and stops the for loop. The logic only validates the first radiobutton. Maybe thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong logic inside the loop, try this:

```
var getForm = document.getElementById('formX');
var putForm = getForm.onsubmit = showIt;

function showIt(){

  var getNames = document.getElementsByName('season');

  var result = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++){
    if(getNames[i].checked){
      alert('You\'ve chosen ' + getNames[i].value)
      result = true
    } 
    if (i == getNames.length - 1 && !result)
    {
        alert('Please, choose an option')
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I was really stuck trying to get `alert('Please, choose')` only when all boxes were unchecked. Now I understand how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how do I make it work, there are several good suggestions in the answers.

If you want to know: "Why didn't it work using the first method?" The best answer is that the `break;` line was causing your loop to terminate immediately, and therefore preventing the `alert("You've chosen...")` from having the opportunity to trigger.

Comment: Yes, exactly as my answer stated.

Comment: Obviously it's "return false" but that's working correctly. The only time it DOESN'T work is when you select winter, and it skips the `alert("You've chosen...")`

BRogers, I voted you up, but I don't have enough rep to comment on yours and give my opinion, so I did my own answer to support yours

Comment: @Leo I see your point I suppose, it would have been cleaner to simply always execute the last line outside of the loop... but the question wasn't asking for a solution to make it work, it was asking WHY it didn't work the first way, and the best answer is that his inclusion of `break` was causing unexpected behavior

Comment: @msanteler - No problem :) - thanks. Anyway. Leo... You failed to read the question fully. He wanted to know why it worked when he pulled it out of the loop. This is because of the `break;`